# How to read a timestamp from a Buffer using the Buffer native API?

Tags: node.js, buffer

### Background

I am reading buffers using the Node.js buffer native API. This API has two functions called `readUIntBE` and `readUIntLE` for Big Endian and Little Endian respectively.

https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_buf_readuintbe_offset_bytelength_noassert

### Problem

By reading the docs, I stumbled upon the following lines:

- byteLength  Number of bytes to read. Must satisfy: 0 < byteLength <= 6.

This means that I can only read 6 bytes at a time using this function, which makes it useless for my use case, as I need to read a timestamp comprised of 8 bytes.

Originally I thought this was a typo in the docs, but after getting a response from @BridgeAR  it was clear this is intended behavior:

- https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/20249#issuecomment-383899009

He mentions that I can  read multiple entries by adding the offset, but it is not clear to me how this could be done.

### Questions

1. How can you read a timestamp that is more that 6 bytes long by continuously adding the offset?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Answer

Simply put, you can't. Not using *only* the native Buffer API anyway.

### Why?

Because Javascript only supports Number up to 53 bits of precision, 8 bytes Numbers ( which have 64 bits ) are not supported. Thus, any attempt to read a Number from a Buffer greater than 6 bytes in length will result in loss of precision and won't be reliable.

### What can I do ?

You need to use a 3rd party library to make computations and display such numbers.

### How did I do it?

In my case, since I only need to print out the Number ( timestamp ) without any loss of precision and I don't need to run computations on it, I used this library:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/int64-buffer

Then it becomes simple. With 3 steps, I can print my timestamp without any loss of precision, Assuming I have a buffer `buf` with an arbitrary length containing my 8 byte Number:

```
const Uint64BE = require("int64-buffer").Uint64BE;
const numberBytes = buff.slice( 0, 8 );
cons number = new Uint64BE( numberBytes );
console.log( number.toString() );
```

### Caveat

If you need to perform operation on such Numbers, I recommend rading the Github discussion https://github.com/nodejs/help/issues/1231

Also, you need to know if your Numbers are LE or BE. That's about it.

Hope it helps!